# Generic HTTPClient or Ajax Class

Tags: javascript

```
var url = "https://www.appcelerator.com";
var service = someservicename;
var xhr = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({
    onload: function(e) {
        // this.responseText holds the raw text return of the message (used for JSON)
        // this.responseXML holds any returned XML (used for SOAP web services)
        // this.responseData holds any returned binary data
        Ti.API.debug(this.responseText);
        alert('success');
    },
    onerror: function(e) {
        Ti.API.debug(e.error);
        alert('error');
    },
    timeout:5000
});

xhr.open("post", url);
xhr.send(someservicename);
```

Here is how i am making my async calls, but how would i make it in a class and send the url, and the requrired service... as **parameters**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var JSONCall = function(url,servic, onLoad, onError){
    // API Url to call
    this.url = url;
    this.service = service;
};
JSONCall.prototype = {
    call: function(){
        var JsonClient = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient();
        JsonClient.open("POST", this.url);
        //setting Request Header
        JsonClient.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
        JsonClient.send(service);    
        JsonClient.onload = this.onLoad;
        JsonClient.onerror = this.onError;

    }
};

// create callbacks
var onLoad = function(response){ /* do something with response */ },
    onError = function(error){ /* do something with error  */ };
// create instance
var jsonCall = new JSONCall(url,"servicename", myLoad, myError);
// do a call
jsonCall.call();
```

I hope you are expecting something like this. You can use this, prototype does the job.